# TypeError when using string formatting

Tags: python

It is saying TypeError on line12 of createAccount(). I passed the balance variable which is float type and thought that the string formatting would convert it into float with 2 decimal places. Not sure why I am getting TypeError

```
from datetime import datetime

def menu():
    selection = int(input("Enter 1 to create and account:\nEnter 2 to deposit:\nEnter 3 to withdraw\nEnter 4 to quit: "))
    return selection

def createAccount():
    name = input("Enter customer name: ")
    filename = '{}.txt'.format(name)
    balance = float(input("Enter the initial deposit amount: "))
    with open(filename,'w') as balance:
        print('The balance is ${:.2f}'.format(balance))
        balance.write('{:.2f}\n'.format(balance))
    with open('log.txt','a') as log:
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        log.write('{},customer:{}\n'.format(timestamp,name))
        log.write('transactiontype:deposit:amt:{.2f\n}'.format(balance))

def deposit():
    name = input("Enter customer name: ")
    filename = '{}.txt'.format(name)
    deposit = float(input("Enter the deposit amount: "))
    with open(filename,'r') as balance:
        current_balance = balance.readline()
        number = current_balance.rstrip()
        new_balance = float(number) + deposit
        print('Your new balance is ${:.2f}'.format(new_balance))
    with open(filename,'w') as balance:
        balance.write('{:.2f\n}'.format(new_balance))
    with open('log.txt','a') as log:
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        log.write('{},customer:{}\n'.format(timestamp,name))
        log.write('transactiontype:deposit:amt:{.2f\n}'.format(deposit))

def withdraw():
    name = input("Enter customer name: ")
    filename = '{}.txt'.format(name)
    withdraw = float(input("Enter the withdrawal amount: "))
    with open(filename,'r') as balance:
        current_balance = balance.readline()
        number = current_balance.rstrip()
        new_balance = float(number) - withdraw
        print('Your new balance is ${:.2f}'.format(new_balance))
    with open(filename,'w') as balance:
        balance.write('{:.2f\n}'.format(new_balance))
    with open('log.txt','a') as log:
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        log.write('{},customer:{}\n'.format(timestamp,name))
        log.write('transactiontype:withdraw:amt:{.2f\n)'.format(withdraw))

selection = None
while selection != 4:
    selection = menu()
    if selection == 1:
        createAccount()
    elif selection == 2:
        deposit()
    elif selection == 3:
        withdraw()
    print()
```

When running the code:
Press 1 to create account
Enter the username
Enter initial deposit
Then the error kicks in.

Comment: You seem to have `\n` inside of format specifiers

Comment: You can use multiple `open()` on the same line, btw. `open('1') as f, open('2') as f2`

Comment: @AlexSkalozub That was the main issue for formatting not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because in the `with` statement there

```
with open(filename,'w') as balance:
    print('The balance is ${:.2f}'.format(balance))
    balance.write('{:.2f}\n'.format(balance))
```

`balance` has become a file handle. The previous user input has been overwritten.

Of course the `format` cannot turn it into a `.2f` string.

Change the line to something like

```
  with open(filename,'w') as balance_file:
```

should fix it.

Comment: oh I see there. I have the file object as balance and the previous balance input variable as same.

Comment: That's the root cause. Please don't forget to accept the answer. ;-)